# How can I restrict access to Amazon EC2 instance, so that even Amazon cannot access it?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

Is there are way I can restrict access to an Amazon EC2 instance, so that no one except me will be able to login to my EC2 instance? I want to restrict access such that not even Amazon data center admins can login to my EC2 instance.  If it is possible, what is the easiest way of doing so?

**EDIT**
To clarify, I understand anyone with physical access to the hardware my EC2 instance is running on, they can get into my EC2 instance if they hack it open.  But, I'm not concerned with that level of security.

Assuming I remove any SSH keys from the EC2 instance, are there any "authorized" ways an Amazon employee could get into my EC2 instance?  And if so, what can be done to prevent them from doing do?

I hope I'm stating my question the right way.  Now that I'm thinking about it in more depth, I realize it might be a tough question to answer.  So, I hope you get the "spirit" of my question, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible that I am aware of. They have physical access, so they can do whatever they want to get in. And who knows what backdoors they have just in case they need to get in.

Comment: Good point about the physical access.  I probably should have clarified that I'm not trying to prevent from intrusion due to not having physical control.  I'm just wondering about getting in via an SSH key or the like.  I will update my question to reflect.

Comment: I could install monitoring software, which would notify me if the EC2 instance was taken down.  WIth that installed, at least I would know if any tampering happened.  That would be good enough for my purposes.

Comment: @MikeyE This isn't going to happen unless a nation-state requests Amazon to do it. If nation states are in your threat model, you probably should not be on Amazon or any public cloud at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton good point, thanks for that.  Just to clarify, can you give an example of who you would consider to be a nation state?

Comment: P.S. My EC2 instances are in the US serving only US customers.  And I live in the US.  Hopefully that adds clarity.

Comment: @MikeyE For example, the USA, Russia, China, France, Spain, Mexico, ...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, it might be worthwhile shooting Amazon the question. You will get an answer that we would all get most likely. If there is some inside baseball type access, most of us would not know about it.

I would also assume, depending on their virtualization platform, they have some console-like access anyway. It always bothered me that they did not have something like that, but maybe it is a security function to not have that type of access. I've never dove that deep into AWS.

Comment: I have a dedicated server hosted by Namecheap.  When I asked them if I locked myself out of the server how could they help me get back in they told me they have no way to gain root access because it is an "unmanaged server".  I presume Amazon has something similar.  I'm not asking how to protect against "hackers" and the like.  I'm just asking given Amazon's published policies, do they have a way to gain access to my box?  I understand they could back-door or hack their way in, but that's outside the scope of my question.

Comment: I actually run a company that does web hosting, VPS, and Dedicated server hosting. Namecheap probably does not want to spend the time to do it for you, they're a large company. If you have out of band management via their portal, you can do it yourself though. It's very simple. Depending on your OS, I can get your root password reset no problemo. It would require a reboot though. I could do it in person, or via ilo/idrac/ipmi; lights out management-different server manufacturers call it a different name.

Comment: Thanks for the info Anthony.  You confirmed my suspicions and answered my question.  I was thinking I could put some kind of monitoring or send an email when the server shuts down to detect an reboot from an unauthorized person.  But, it would be better to have my servers under lock and key.  I actually found an ISP who offers a server cabinet, which can only be physically accessed by a key, which only me and the data center director will have.  So, I'm going to use them and if business goes well, stand up a data center in a year of my own in a year or two.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, if you want to be more physical control, you need to colocate your own equipment. Some places have badge access, not just lock and key to cages which can be nice.

Comment: Good point.  The ISP I am colocating my servers in has both, along with a few other security procedures and the like.